# Need to run docker run command inside python script

Tags: python, docker

My Docker Command is:

```
docker run --rm wappalyzer/cli https://wappalyzer.com
```

When I run my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import call
import json
import os
import docker

docker run --rm wappalyzer/cli "MYURL"
```

it says

```
File "t.py", line 7
    docker run --rm wappalyzer/cli "MYURL"
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My os is ubuntu 14.04 and I am using ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Maybe you should look at `os.system()` or `subprocess.checkoutput()`, just pasting your commandline into a program, whithout even quoting it is not going to work.

Answer (score 27):

As @AndyShinn says, Python is not a shell language, but you can call to docker as if you were running a shell command:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

with open("/tmp/output.log", "a") as output:
    subprocess.call("docker run --rm wappalyzer/cli https://wappalyzer.com", shell=True, stdout=output, stderr=output)
```

With this approach you don't need to import docker.

Comment: Instead displaying in the terminal i need to redirect above command out put to a text file.Please can you help me to solve that.I'm new to both Ubuntu and python.

Comment: I've added the file output.

Comment: You're welcome: [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 15):

This isn't valid Python code. If you are just looking to run a container and passing a command as an argument, you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import docker

image = "wappalyzer/cli"

client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run(image,  sys.argv[1], True)
```

But you should read up more about Python and running processes from Python if that is what you are after. Python is not a shell language and you can't just use shell commands inline.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE : 2021-03-22**

We now have [python-on-whales](https://pypi.org/project/python-on-whales/)
A Docker client for Python. Works on Linux, macOS, and Windows, for Python 3.7 and above.

```
>>> from python_on_whales import docker
>>> output = docker.run("hello-world")
>>> print(output)
Hello from Docker! This message shows that your installation appears to be 
working correctly.
>>> from python_on_whales import DockerClient
>>> docker = DockerClient(compose_files=["./my-compose-file.yml"])
>>> docker.compose.build()
>>> docker.compose.up()
...
>>> docker.compose.down()
```

Comment: see https://github.com/gabrieldemarmiesse/python-on-whales/issues/188

Comment: The post shows "UPDATE : 2022-03-22", so it's from the future?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a pip package named `docker` and use it to connect to the Docker.
The difference between running a command in subProcess and this solution is the format. You can manage your images, containers, and everything a CLI is capable of.

Check it out here: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Sample:

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()

client.containers.run("ubuntu", "echo hello world")

# or

client.containers.run("bfirsh/reticulate-splines", detach=True)

# you can even stream your output like this:
for line in container.logs(stream=True):
   print(line.strip())
```

All code samples are available at the source URL I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Edge cases and parameterization of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44866349/913098) follow.

It is also better to use `subprocess.run` over `subprocess.call`

```
import docker
import subprocess
import os
import time


def main():
    client, log_path = _set_up_environment()
    _run_docker_compose("docker-compose-with-rabbit.yaml", log_path)


def _run_docker_compose(docker_compose_name, log_path):
    bash_command = f"docker-compose -f {docker_compose_name}} up -d"
    _execute_shell_command(bash_command, log_path)


def _execute_shell_command(bash_command, log_path):
    with open(log_path, "w") as output:
        subprocess.run(
            bash_command,
            shell=True,  # pass single string to shell, let it handle.
            stdout=output,
            stderr=output
        )
    while not output.closed:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print(f"{os.linesep} COMMAND {bash_command} LOG OUTPUT:")
    with open(log_path, "r") as output:
        for line in output:
            print(line)


def _create_docker_log_file():
    log_location, log_name = "logs", "output.log"
    log_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), log_location, log_name)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(log_path), exist_ok=True)
    assert os.path.isdir(os.path.dirname(log_path))
    if not os.path.isfile(log_path):
        os.mknod(log_path)

    return log_location, log_name, log_path


def _set_up_environment():
    log_location, log_name, log_path = _create_docker_log_file()
    client = docker.from_env()
    return client, log_path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Not sure of the tradeoffs but here is one using `subprocess.Popen` https://gist.github.com/VietThan/99218291dd64ff835872b0d971acac32